# Add "[]" to JSON string Newtonsoft?

Tags: json, json.net

I have sample json string like this..(here mentioning only 2 values, but real time I have 100+ values)

```
{"CoverNoteInput":{"UserId":"E3434","QuoNo":"12312"},"CoverNoteAddInput":null}
```

How to add `"[]"` for `CoverNoteInput` object?

Desired Output is :

```
{"CoverNoteInput":**[**{"UserId":"D12684-000","QuoNo":"MQ1700001978"}**]**,"CoverNoteAddInput":null}
```

Later I would convert desired output in to Dataset.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you post the C# class you are serializing? You will need to make CoverNoteInput a collection of some kind to make newtonsoft serialize it as an array

Comment: You don't want to "add `[]`". You want to convert the `CoverNoteInput` property to an array containing its original single value. To convert a value `value` to an array, just write `[value]`. So in this case, `obj.CoverNoteInput = [obj.CoverNoteInput];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), you could do this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
jo["CoverNoteInput"] = new JArray(jo["CoverNoteInput"]);
jsonString = jo.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pnvfBp